# Как добавить шрифт в TextMeshPro в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу добавить загруженный шрифт в TextMeshPro на Unity. Как это можно сделать? В дефолтном тексте просто перетаскиваешь и готово. А как быть с ТextМeshPro не знаю

Comment: google -> "ТextМeshPro custom font"

Answer (score 0):

Перетаскиваете ваш шрифт в Unity. Затем Window - Text Mesh Pro - Font Asset Creator. В верхнем поле выбираете шрифт и жмёте Generate Font Atlas и выбираете папку куда сохранить ассет. Если нужно с кириллицей, то в поле Character Set выбираем Unicode Range (Hex) и в поле ниже прописываем 0400-04ff, если нужно ещё с английскими буквами, символами и цифрами, то 0000-04ff